# MathJax in titles?

Tags: discussion

I have a sense that adding MathJax to titles can interfere with questions being picked up correctly by search engines, and so the practice is discouraged when not particularly helpful.

I think I've had my question titles edited to remove mathjax in the past, and for this reason.

However I can't substantiate nor confirm any of this.

I keep wanting to edit the title of [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26852/12102)

> Do all rigid bodies of radius $r$ have at least one stable orbit with perihelion $p$ such that $2r >p > r$?

because it would look essentially the same without MathJax:

> Do all rigid bodies of radius r have at least one stable orbit with perihelion p such that 2r > p > r?

Is there some standard, convention, or consensus on the use of MathJax in titles in cases where it doesn't seem to be necessary? Would making this change be considered heavy-handed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such discussions happened in the past on multiple sites:

- Chemistry: [Is MathJax in titles a problem? And why?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261)
- Computer Science: [Is MathJax in title allowed?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1439)
- Mathematics: [Using MathJax/TeX in the titles of questions - yes or no?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10617)

**UPDATE:** Physics: [Is MathJax in titles OK?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12706/83380)

Summary: if a title can be stated without using MathJax, then it should be, because

- It will be readable in search engine preview
- It will be better understandable to search engine algorithms (who rely on page titles / H1 elements heavily)
- It will be readable in Stack Exchange mobile apps which do not render MathJax in titles ([MathJax borks in titles in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221927/mathjax-borks-in-titles-in-android-app), [Please add TeX rendering in titles on the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231730/please-add-tex-rendering-in-titles-on-the-ios-app)).

And I think that pretty much every title on this site could work without MathJax (unlike on Mathematics where some formula-rich titles  can't be avoided). Certainly for the example you gave.

Comment: Thanks, it seems your answer is well received. I've made the edit to the linked question.

Comment: It also allows the question to be rendered on the Hot Network Questions feed on sites that don't have MathJax installed

Comment: Thanks (belated). That's also mentioned in the new Physics Meta answers I've just added a link to above.